# API to get transactions between 2 blocks in Ethereum

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

Assuming that I have a starting block and an ending block and I want to retrieve all the transactions that have occurred between these two blocks, is there any API that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use web3.js.

In web3, you can [get blocks](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblock)
You can also [get transaction from block](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionfromblock)

I let you check all the other functions available.

Comment: Will I be able to also see all the contracts that are responsible for those transactions in the transaction details of the block?

Comment: Of course. when sending a transaction/call to a contract, the contract address is the "to" parameter.

Comment: According to etherscan.io block # 0 has 8893 transaction https://etherscan.io/block/0, but when I used the command web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount(0), it returned me 0. Am i using the function incorrectly or there is some other error?

Comment: If you check the transaction list, they are not really transaction, but a state of the chain at its very beginning. This state is set with the genesis file. (that's why they are called "GENESIS_XXX")